# Show hide form fields in react using onFocus and onBlur

Tags: reactjs, onblur, onfocus

I'm working on a form that initially only shows one input field and when it is focused, it shows other inputs and the submit button.

I also want to hide all those extra fields if the form loses focus while they are empty. And this is the part that I'm not being able to implement.

This is my code: I use a controlled form and a state to handle focus.

```js
const FoldableForm = () => {
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState(defaultFormState);
  const [hasFocus, setFocus] = useState(false);
  
  const handleOnBlur = () => {
    if (!formState.message.trim() && !formState.other_input.trim()) {
      setFocus(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form
      onFocus={() => setFocus(true)}
      onBlur={handleOnBlur}
    >
      <textarea 
        name="message" 
        onChange={(e) => setFormState({ ...formState, message: e.target.value })}
      />
      {hasFocus && (
        <>
          <input 
            type="text" name="other_input" 
            onChange={(e) => setFormState({ ...formState, message: e.target.other_input })}
          />
          <button type="button">Post comment</button>
        </>
      )}
    </form>
  );
}
```

Currently, if I type something in the text area, `setFocus(false)` is never invoked, so it works as intended.
Otherwise, if I leave it empty and click on the other input field, the `handleOnBlur` function is called, it sets focus to false, so the form is 'minimized'.

This is expected because the blur event (from the textarea) is triggered before the focus event (from the new input field). So I tried to use setTimeout to check, after a fraction of a second if the focus event had already occurred.

To do so, I used a second state (shouldShow) that is updated in a setTimeout inside the handleOnBlue function.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  if(!hasFocus) {
    setShouldShow(false); // this should cause the form to minimize
  }
}, 100);
```

However, according to the react lifecycle, the value of hasFocus that is passed to the setTimeout function is at the invocation time, not at execution. So setTimeout here is useless.

I also tried to use references, but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case i think that the usage of the `shouldShow` state is redundant and you can also avoid using a timeout which may lead to bugs.
You can take advantage of the [FocusEvent.relatedTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent/relatedTarget) attribute and prevent hiding the extra fields when blur from an input and focus to another happens simultaneously.

The `handleOnBlur` function should look like this:

```
  const handleOnBlur = (e) => {
    if (e.relatedTarget && e.relatedTarget.name === "other_input") return;

    if (!formState.message.trim() && !formState.other_input.trim()) {
      setFocus(false);
    }
  };
```

You can find a working example in this code [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-gianmarco-fclbbh?file=/src/App.js:226-437).

The problem with this approach is that if you have multiple fields appearing you need to check if any of those is focused like below:

```
["other_input", "another_input"].includes(e.relatedTarget.name)
```

Comment: I implemented it using `ie.relatedTarget?.form === e.target.form` to check if the focused input/button belongs to the same form

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is because of [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) in JavaScript. The value of `hasFocus` is not the value of the variable at the moment your callback inside `setTimeout` is executed. It's the value when the `onBlur` callback is executed.

One solution would be to use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).

Define a state which holds both `hasFocus` and `shouldShow` inside:

```
  const [state, setState] = useState({ hasFocus: false, shouldShow: false });
```

When you try to access the previous state using functional updates, you get the most recent value:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    setState((state) => {
        if (!state.hasFocus) {
            return { ...state, shouldShow: false };
        }

        return state;
     });
}, 100);
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-danny-dlduev?file=/src/App.js)

Another solution would be to debounce a function which sets the `hasFocus` state to false, which imo is way better.

Comment: Thanks, I tested it and it works. It is smart to use a complex state to be able to use a functional update to get the current value of hasFocus while updating shouldShow.

Comment: I'm trying to use the approach with the debounce solution without the shouldShow state and I cannot figure it out

Comment: If you want to hide other fields as soon as user focuses on other elements rather than the other input, the @fgkolf's answer is perfect. But if you want to wait a few milliseconds/seconds and then hide the input, you better debounce your `handleOnBlur` function. Search for `debounce` and `useDebouncedCallback` keywords. You will find the implementations and probably blog posts explaining them.